# Basic on free morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety of dimension $n$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and let $f: \mathbb{P}^{1} \rightarrow X$ be a nonconstant morphism. Then

$$f^{\ast}T_{X} \cong \mathcal{O}(a_{1}) \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathcal{O}(a_{n}),$$
where we assume $a_{1} \geq \cdots \geq a_{n}$. How to prove that $f^{\ast}T_{X}$ contains $T_{\mathbb{P}^{1}} \cong \mathcal{O}(2)$ and $a_{1} \geq 2$?

Thank you!

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I am not missing any hypothesis. I titled "Basic on free morphism" because this kind of problem appears when one studies free morphisms. This question is a remark on Debarre's Higher-Dimensional Algebraic Geometry, chap 4, sec. 2, p. 90.

Comment: Dear @rla: you're right, I misread the question. I will delete my comment.

Comment: To answer the question: the differential $df$ gives a generically injective map of $T_{\mathbf P^1}$ into $f^* T_X$, which shows that $T_{\mathbf P^1}$ is a subsheaf of $f^* T_X$. If we had $a_1<2$, then the map from $T_{\mathbf P^1} \rightarrow f^*T_X$ composed with any of the projections would be zero, but that contradicts injectivity.

Comment: Dear @AsalBeagDubh, why the generically injectivity of $T_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}$ into $f^{\ast}T_{X}$ implies the inclusion of sheaves? Sorry, but I am not familiar with this facts.

Comment: Dear rla, the map $df: T_{\mathbf P^1} \rightarrow f^*T_X$ is zero at only finitely many points of $\mathbf P^1$. That means it is not identically zero in a neighbourhood of any point, hence it is not zero on any stalk. But since $T_{\mathbf P^1}$ is a line bundle, its stalk at any point is just a free rank-1 module over the local ring, so nonzero implies injective. Finally a morphism of sheaves is injective iff it is injective on stalks. I hope that helps.